# Netbeans fast imports

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using Netbeans and am trying to use the fast import quick keys(Alt+Shift+I) but when I do this the box displays No "Classes Found". any ideas? I have have updated everything in the hope that this was the issue, but alas nothing has changed. i have also gone through the options - keymaps, and my setting are the same as the guy next to me.

Comment: On Window it is CTRL+SHIFT+I. Otherwise it could be due to other errors in your code (missing brackets etc.). Can you show the code?

Answer (score 6):

**Alt+Shift+I** is using for **Fixing selected class's import**. For example if you are using `SimpleDateFormat`. When cursor in `SimpleDateFormat` you can check fix selected class's import. If class not imported you can import.
[image]

If you use *Alt+Shift+I* in non-classes you get `<No Classes Found>`. 
For importing class you must click. If you want to import two or more you can use **Ctrl-Shift-I**. For more information see this: [Netbeans ShortCuts](https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/usersguide/shortcuts-74.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

"Alt + Shift + I" fixes selected class's import. When there is no selection Netbeans tries to fix the import for the element, the cursor is on.

Use Ctrl + Shift + I to fix all imports for the whole file.

Answer (score 3):

Use Ctrl + Shift + I will import all the required packages.